# Rewritten URL Not Picking Up ID PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, get

I've rewritten my URL's using .htaccess and everything is working fine for the redirection, however the ID of the selected article isn't being found.

My URL has changed from `http://www/website.co.uk/news.php?id=111111` to `http://www.website.co.uk/news/111111` using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^news.php$ /news/%1? [L,R]
```

However, Inside the news.php page I catch the ID number using:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
$id = $_GET["id"];
}
else{
header("Location: redirect.php?type=error");
exit();
```

So when I run the page now, it is redirecting to the redirect.php page as it isn't Getting the ID. How can I sort this error?

Comment: You need to do more debugging than just letting it redirect to the error page. See what $_GET has in it so you can see if the array is empty. Put `print_r($_GET);exit;` at the top of the page. And when you visit your URL you'll be able to see what's in the array.  Also your write doesn't look like if you're using clean URL's. It appears backwards.

Comment: The printed output is simply `Array ( )`

Answer (score 0):

You've written an external redirect, which points the user's browser to `http://www.website.co.uk/news/111111`. And that is exactly the URL, your server will see - so, there is no ID parameter in the URL. You have to add one more line to your `.htaccess` to *internally* rewrite that URL to the old (parametrized) one:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) news.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

The user will still see the rewritten URL without parameter, but your PHP script will get the old one (`news.php?id=111111`).

Comment: Thank you, I can see what you mean by this but unfortunately the above script still redirects to the error page

Comment: Hm, I wonder why your server delegates the request to news.php at all. Because there is only a directory "news" mentioned in the URL `/news/111111`. Have you posted your complete `.htaccess`?
Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at the top of your `.htaccess`. If that fails too, you can still go with Shane Reeves solution, which is based on the rewritten URL, but requires more work to do in the script picking up the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP's preg_split() method to split the URI into usable values.

```
<?php
define('APPLICATION_URL', 'http://website.co.uk/');
$url = str_replace(APPLICATION_URL, null, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urlData = preg_split('/[\/\?]/', $url);
echo $urlData[0] . '/' . $urlData[1];
?>
```

The above code should output: `news/111111`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^news.php$ /news/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^news/(.*) news.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

The second `RewriteRule` should silently rewrite the url back to the original url so the user still sees `news/11111`, but your php page should pick up the `id` value.

EDIT: Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
#External redirect with THE_REQUEST trick; change R to R=301 when everything works correctly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /news\.php\?id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /news/%2\? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) /news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working either - The URL redirects to /news/111111 perfectly but it just won't let the script pick up the ID. I was really hoping that I could get this to work

Comment: No, The page is still redirecting to the error page - I took out the GET PHP script from the news page and the url redirects to `website.co.uk/news/GET`

Comment: Are you entering `http://www.website.co.uk/news.php?id=111111` or `http://www.website.co.uk/news/111111` link and getting the error?

Comment: I removed everything from my htaccess file and only entered the code below the `EDIT: Try this one` line and tried a few different ids and they all worked for me. Try a hard refresh on the page/try a different id that you haven't used before.

Comment: OK, I tried that but it's still not picking it up - Also there is no formatting of the page, like the CSS file is being blocked. I tried Shane Reeves's method below and that actually does work when combined with your .htaccess code but again the CSS formatting does not exist

Comment: That is really strange, do you have any other rules in your htaccess file? For the css add a `/` before the css link e.g. `<a href="/css/etc` or add ``<base href="website">` inside the `<head>` tags on your page

Comment: No the only rule is what I showed on the original post. I've used that and combined it with the PHP provided by Shane and put a slash before all of the CSS scripts and it is now working correctly. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Wait, you only had one RewriteRule in your htaccess? you need to put both of the RewriteRules.